# Pandas groupby add rows with cross references

Tags: python, pandas

Given a simple example of a dataframe like this:

```
sample  chrom   start   stop    count   psi5
sampleA chr1    100     200     75      0.75
sampleA chr1    100     250     25      0.25
sampleB chr1    100     200     50      1.0
sampleC chr1    100     250     50      1.0
sampleD chr1    100     300     1       NaN
```

How can I add rows for each sample, that doesn't have an observation for all the unique values of column 3 (0-based)?

```
sampleA chr1    100 200 75  0.75
sampleA chr1    100 250 25  0.25
sampleB chr1    100 200 50  1.0
sampleC chr1    100 250 50  1.0
sampleD chr1    100 300 1   NaN
sampleA chr1    100 300 0   0
sampleB chr1    100 250 0   0
sampleB chr1    100 300 0   0
sampleC chr1    100 200 0   0
sampleC chr1    100 300 0   0
sampleD chr1    100 200 NaN NaN
sampleD chr1    100 250 NaN NaN
```

So `sampleA` didn't have an observation for column 3 = `300`, so we added that row with zeros in columns 4 and 5. But the tricky part happens with `sampleD`, which had only `count` of `1`, so it didn't pass criteria and thus its value for `psi5` is NaN, and either could be skipped since I'll probably do a pivot table from this and fill emtpy with na, or add a row with `NaN`s.

This code does what I would like to do, with a small example: https://gist.github.com/olgabot/1b4234c28b245e52bfc0

But it's not well vectorized.

Comment: You have the following line in your expected output (the 5th line): `sampleD chr1    100 300 50  1.0`. I assume that's a typo and you want `sampleD chr1    100 300 NaN NaN` because it is for `SampleD`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use `stack` and `unstack` to do this in a vectorized way. The NaNs for sampleD are a bitt tricky because I need to use the Nan caused by unstacking to fill in the stop column. But you can either get rid of sampleD at the beginning are add the NaN to sampleD at the end (that's what I will do):

All at once:

```
df = df.set_index(['sample','chrom','start','stop'])
df = df.unstack(['sample','chrom','start']).fillna(0)
df = df.stack(['sample','chrom','start']).reset_index()
df.loc[df.sample == 'sampleD',['count','psi5']] = np.nan
print df

   stop   sample chrom  start  count  psi5
0    200  sampleA  chr1    100     75  0.75
1    200  sampleB  chr1    100     50  1.00
2    200  sampleC  chr1    100      0  0.00
3    200  sampleD  chr1    100    NaN   NaN
4    250  sampleA  chr1    100     25  0.25
5    250  sampleB  chr1    100      0  0.00
6    250  sampleC  chr1    100     50  1.00
7    250  sampleD  chr1    100    NaN   NaN
8    300  sampleA  chr1    100      0  0.00
9    300  sampleB  chr1    100      0  0.00
10   300  sampleC  chr1    100      0  0.00
11   300  sampleD  chr1    100    NaN   NaN
```

*Step by Step*

1) Set ['sample','chrom','start','stop'] as the index:

```
df = df.set_index(['sample','chrom','start','stop'])
print df

                          count  psi5
sample  chrom start stop             
sampleA chr1  100   200      75  0.75
                    250      25  0.25
sampleB chr1  100   200      50  1.00
sampleC chr1  100   250      50  1.00
sampleD chr1  100   300       1   NaN
```

2) Unstack on all the indices except stop and fill the missing values created by unstack with zero:

```
df = df.unstack(['sample','chrom','start'])
print df

          count                                psi5                           
sample  sampleA  sampleB  sampleC  sampleD  sampleA  sampleB  sampleC  sampleD
chrom      chr1     chr1     chr1     chr1     chr1     chr1     chr1     chr1
start       100      100      100      100      100      100      100      100
stop                                                                          
200          75       50      NaN      NaN     0.75        1      NaN      NaN
250          25      NaN       50      NaN     0.25      NaN        1      NaN
300         NaN      NaN      NaN        1      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN

df = df.fillna(0)
print df

          count                                psi5                           
sample  sampleA  sampleB  sampleC  sampleD  sampleA  sampleB  sampleC  sampleD
chrom      chr1     chr1     chr1     chr1     chr1     chr1     chr1     chr1
start       100      100      100      100      100      100      100      100
stop                                                                          
200          75       50        0        0     0.75        1        0        0
250          25        0       50        0     0.25        0        1        0
300           0        0        0        1     0.00        0        0        0
```

3) Now restack to back to the old panel form but now each grouping has a stop value of 200, 250, and 300:

```
df = df.stack(['sample','chrom','start']).reset_index()
print df 

    stop   sample chrom  start  count  psi5
0    200  sampleA  chr1    100     75  0.75
1    200  sampleB  chr1    100     50  1.00
2    200  sampleC  chr1    100      0  0.00
3    200  sampleD  chr1    100      0  0.00
4    250  sampleA  chr1    100     25  0.25
5    250  sampleB  chr1    100      0  0.00
6    250  sampleC  chr1    100     50  1.00
7    250  sampleD  chr1    100      0  0.00
8    300  sampleA  chr1    100      0  0.00
9    300  sampleB  chr1    100      0  0.00
10   300  sampleC  chr1    100      0  0.00
11   300  sampleD  chr1    100      1  0.00
```

4) Add back the NaN for sampleD:

```
df.loc[df.sample == 'sampleD',['count','psi5']] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using pandas and that your data is a .csv file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd

cols = ['sample', 'chrom', 'start', 'stop', 'count', 'psi5']    #  Name Columns
data = pd.read_csv('./stuff.txt', header=False, names=cols, sep=',',index_col=False)    #  Import data

for letters in data.sample.unique():
    missing = {200,250,300} - set(data[data.sample==letters].stop)
    for m in missing:
        data = data.append(pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(cols, [[letters], ['chr1'], [100], [m], [0], [0]]))))

data = data.reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1)

data.head(12)

#out[1]:
```

[image]